# How can I add a watch over $validator.errors in Vue.js, Vee Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I wanted to add a watch on $validator.errors, so that whenever there is any error I want it to be logged,

I did the same by checking the length of errors and then assigning the self.errors.all() to a variable,

But I was wondering if I can directly apply the watch on errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using vee-validate 2.x?

The `$validator.errors` is automatically injected as `errors` in your components so you can directly watch them:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  watch: {
    errors (val) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @logaretm its good suggestion, but unfortunately I am using old 1.2 in the project that's why I need help

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: In case anyone faces the same issue and is using version below 2.x, here is how we can get it done.

```
computed: {
        formErrors: function() {
            return this.$validator.errors;
        }
```

As we are sending forms for validation, we can compute the $validator.errors and the apply a watch on the formErrors, this works

```
watch:{
      formErrors : {
          handler:function(value){
              var formName = this.paymentMode;
              if(value.items.length > 0){
                  value.items.forEach(function(val){
                     console.log(val.msg);
                  });
              }
          },
          deep:true
      }
    }
```